# Javacard security design: all smartcards the same public and private key a good idea?

Tags: java, security, private-key

I am designing a concept where a system should communicate securely with a smartcard. 
The design is like this:
[smartcard] **<->** [software on a pc in a store] **<->** [server in the cloud]
The smartcard should communicate securely with the cloud and should prevent eavesdropping on the connection, as well the software on the pc in the store.
My question: is it a good idea to use the same public/private key for all smartcards? Or should I use a new one for each card?
Of course it's easy to implement one card so the cloud knows which public keys it should use for the various encryption schemes.

Comment: Short answer: no. Use different keys.

Comment: @Henry: Thanks! Can you throw in a short explanation why?

Comment: See Elliott's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the same public key on all of the cards is a **terrible** idea; if someone compromises one (through theft or other means) then ***all*** of the transactions for ***all stores*** are compromised. If each store uses a unique key, a compromised key is limited in scope to one store.

**tl;dr** Use a unique public/private key per store.

Comment: For the store I am completely with you. But I mean the cards itself?

Comment: @yoano The smartcard is what authenticates the store, and contains the means of securing the communications channel; namely the public/private key pair.